# Why does JSON_MODIFY using append not append as expected

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following (minimal) [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c3041f836343d65487e646ab2be937d6)

```sql
-- prepare some data
DECLARE @src TABLE (txt varchar(MAX), id bigint)
insert into @src (txt, id) values ('foo', 1)
insert into @src (txt, id) values ('bar', 1)
insert into @src (txt, id) values ('baz', 1)
insert into @src (txt, id) values ('foo', 2)
insert into @src (txt, id) values ('bar', 2)

-- prepare json 
declare @dst TABLE (json varchar(max), id bigint)
insert into @dst (json, id) values ('[]', 1)
insert into @dst (json, id) values ('[]', 2)

-- peek the expected result
select s.txt, d.id from @src s 
inner join @dst d
on d.id = s.id

-- now update
update @dst set json = JSON_MODIFY(d.json, 'append strict $', s.txt)
from @src s 
inner join @dst d
on d.id = s.id

-- let's see
select * from @dst
```

I would expect the result to be `['foo', 'bar', 'baz']` for id `1` in the `@dst` table.
I have one very similar case in which this works but I can't get it working again.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, the `UPDATE` statement is not deterministic, because the statement includes a `FROM` clause that returns more than one value for the `json` column. This is explained in the "Best practices" part of the [documentation](http://Best%20practices): *Use caution when specifying the FROM clause to provide the criteria for the update operation. The results of an UPDATE statement are undefined if the statement includes a FROM clause that is not specified in such a way that only one value is available for each column occurrence that is updated, that is if the UPDATE statement is not deterministic.*

But you may change your approach and build the expected JSON array with `STRING_AGG()` or `FOR XML PATH`(if `STRING_AGG()` is not available). Notice, that you can't build a JSON array of scalar values using `FOR JSON`.

```
UPDATE @dst
SET json = a.json
FROM @dst d
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT CONCAT('[', STRING_AGG('"' + txt + '"', ','), ']') AS json
   FROM @src s
   WHERE s.id = d.id
) a
```

Result:

```
json                id
----------------------
["foo","bar","baz"] 1
["foo","bar"]       2
```